# How to split list of data with ranges till list finish its data

Tags: python, for-loop

I read data from .ini file, then after getting all data, I want to split it by 48 bytes. For example, data has information like this: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10....56.
So I have to split this data 
data_1(6 bytes): 1,2,3,4,5,6
data_2 (7 bytes): 7,8,9,10,11,12,13
data_3 (7 bytes):14,...,20
.
.
.
data 7(7 bytes): ... 48
then after first itiretion code has to start write data to 6 byte field again till writing all data from the list

```
f = open("b.ini", "r")
data = list(f.read())
ftp_data = [data]
#print (ftp_data)
for i in range(ftp_data):
    data_1 = ftp_data[0:6]
    data_2 = ftp_data[7:14]
    print (ftp_data)
```

Comment: Why is it 6+7+7+.... and why not 8 + 8+..

Comment: Because we trying to send information to equipment which receives 48 bytes, so it is diviede by data 1=6bytes, others 7bytes

Comment: But then what really is the problem now? What is your expected output? You can get this by slicing the list.

Comment: For example: I have a list data = ['1','2','3'......'56']. I want to get data_1=[6 bytes data], data_2=[7bytes data], data_3=[7bytes data], data_4 = [7bytes data], data_5[7 bytes data],data_6[7 bytes data],data_7[7 bytes data](total 48 bytes), so at this step code must start again to split data. Because our list has 56 bytes, howevere it should start again with 6 bytes and so on.